# Time aligned variable in stata

Tags: panel, stata

I have a panel data set for multiple waves (13) for roughly 10,000 individuals each year, with people entering and exiting at various time points. I am interested in what happens as people become diagnosed with a disease over time. Therefore I need to recode the time variable so that it becomes `t=0` the first wave when diagnosed, then `t=1` is the next year and so on, so that all of my individuals are comparable (and I guess `-1` for `t-1` etc). However I am unsure about how to go about this in `stata`. Would anyone be able to advise? Many thanks

Comment: For future questions, please provide attempts you've made in the form of code. You show no research effort within your post. See the **Asking** section on http://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: Apologies for this, I had originally got to "by id: gen t=_n" and were then trying to find a way to manipulate _n and year but was struggling. Will provide working out in further uses though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple but not optimal solution**

Suppose `diagnosis` is 1 when diagnosed (at most once per person) and 0 otherwise. 
Then the time at diagnosis is at its simplest

```
 egen time_diagnosis = total(diagnosis * year), by(id)
```

but you need to ignore any zeros. To spell that out,

```
 replace time_diagnosis = . if time_diagnosis == 0
```

**Better alternative**

A more complicated but preferable alternative can handle multiple diagnoses if they occur:

```
 egen time_diagnosis = min(year / diagnosis), by(id)
```

as `year / diagnosis` is `year` when `diagnosis` is 1 and missing otherwise. This yields missing values if there is no diagnosis, which is as it should be.

Then you subtract that to get a new time variable.

```
 gen time2 = time - time_diagnosis
```

In short, I think you can get this done in two statements, handling panel structure too.

**Update**

@Richard Herron asks why use `egen` with `by()`, and not just

```
 gen time_diagnosis = time * diagnosis
```

A limitation of that is that the "correct" value is contained only in those observations for which `diagnosis` is 1; that value still has to be "spread" to other values for the same `id`. But that is precisely what `egen` does here. In the simplest situation, with one diagnosis the total of `time * diagnosis` is just `time * 1` or `time`, as any zeros make no difference to the sum.

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to get `time_diagnosis` without `merge`! But why `egen time_diagnosis = total(diagnosis * year), by(id)` rather than `generate time_diagnosis = diagnosis * year`? Is that just to flow more clearly to your multiple diagnosis example? Or is `total` required? Thanks.

Comment: See extra details above.

Answer (score 2):

**The case of one diagnosis per person**

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 100
set seed 2357

generate id = _n
generate year = floor(10 * runiform()) + 1990
expand 5

bysort id: replace year = year + _n
bysort id (year): generate diag = cond(_n == 3, 1, 0)

list in 1/20, sepby(id)

*----- what you seek -----

bysort id (diag): gen time = year - year[_N]

sort id year
list in 1/20
```

I assume the same data structure as @RichardHerron and use his example. `diag` is an indicator variable that takes on the value of 1 at the time of diagnosis and 0 otherwise (only one diagnosis per person is considered).

The sorting done by `bysort` is critical. The observation holding the time of diagnosis is pushed to the end of the database (by `id` groups) and then all that's left to do is compare (subtract) all `year`s with that reference year. See `help _variables` for details on *system variables* like `_N`.

**The case of multiple diagnoses per person**

If several diagnoses are made per person, but we care only for the first occurence (according to `year`), we could do:

```
gsort id diag -year
by id: gen time = year - year[_N]
```

Comment: I agree with @Richard Herron. This is a nice use of `by:` and incidentally echoes the sort of thing that `egen` does under the hood. Note that it is  fine to emphasise the assumption that diagnosis occurs at most once; and also fine to have technique for when an event may occur repeatedly, but interest is in the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually helpful to provide test data, but here they are easy enough to generate. The trick is to find the first year for each individual (my `fyear`), which I'll do with `min()` from `egen`. Then I'll subtract this first year `fyear` from the actual year to find the year relative to diagnosis `ryear`.

```
/* generate panel */
clear
set obs 10000
generate id = _n
generate year = floor(10 * runiform()) + 1990
expand 10
bysort id: replace year = year + _n
sort id year
list in 1/20

/* generate relative year */
bysort id: egen fyear = min(year)
generate ryear = year - fyear
list in 1/20
```

If the first year in the panel is not diagnosis, then just construct `fyear` based on diagnosis criteria.

---

Edit: Thinking more on this, maybe it's the last part that you're having a hard time with (i.e., identifying the diagnosis year to subtract from the calendar year). Here's what I would do.

```
bysort id (year): generate diagnosis = cond(_n == 5, 1, 0)
preserve
tempfile diagnosis
keep if (diagnosis == 1)
rename year dyear
keep id dyear
save `diagnosis'
restore
merge m:1 id using `diagnosis', nogenerate
generate ryear2 = year - dyear
```